# Regex: filter out prerelease tags

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some tags:

```
tag-4.2.23.1
tag-4.2.23-beta.1.365
tag-4.2.23
```

Im trying to build a regex expressions to filter out the `tag-4.2.23-beta.1.365`

So far I got this one working on https://regexr.com/ : 
`4\.2\.23[^-]`

But when using it in PowerShell

```
$tags | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex }
```

it only gives me the `tag-4.2.23.1`

Comment: Could you provide the full relevant code to repro the issue? Besides, a lookahead is more appropriate here, `4\.2\.23(?!-)`, or better, ``\b4\.2\.23\b(?!-)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the string boundaries. For instance you can have a very generic

```
/\A\w+-\d+(\.\d+)*\z/
```

Expanded:

```
/(?x)       # (freespacing marker)
  \A        # start of string
  \w+       # initial tag name (change it if tags can contain non-word characters)
  -         # separator dash
  \d+       # major version number
  (\.\d+)*  # other parts of the version. Change the quantifier if needed
            # for instance to {2,3} to match only 3- and 4-part versions.
  \z        # end of string
/
```

Or have a very specific

```
/\Atag-4\.2\.23(\.\d+)?\z/
```

to only match optional subpatch numbers after `4.2.23`